# How to print .pdf and .doc extension files from folder on specific time

Tags: vba, printing, schedule

In my work schedule i need to print some paper work daily . they all  got name  by specific date. eg: jan11.pdf, jan12.pdf, jan13.pdf,
i wants to schedule them to print daily by date . for example if today is 11 January, it should print jan11.pdf file.  is there any programming way to schedule them  without any third party software.

Comment: Windows Task Scheduler and a vbscript or whatever you're familiar with can do that.

Comment: could you please guide me to do with vb script